# Serializing Google Calendar Event with Moshi

Tags: java, android, moshi

I am trying to serialize Google Calendar `Event` which is of `GenericJson`. This is my model class:

```
public class LectureEvent {
    private DateTime dateTime;
    private List<Event> events;     //google calendar event
}
```

This is how I am using `ParametrizedType`:

```
JsonAdapter<List<LectureEvent>> adapter = moshi.adapter(Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, LectureEvent.class));
adapter.toJson(lectureEvents);
```

But I am receiving this error:

> Cannot serialize abstract class com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory

Any idea how to serialize it?

Comment: It sounds like this Event is not a value type. It contains a field declaration of that abstract type. Consider making `@FromJson`-style JSON adapters for the Event type if you really want it in your Java representation of your JSON. example adapter: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/96e074d030a1b72e6263b93e311c4173492ec2a8/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes/CardAdapter.java

Comment: Actually I have tried with Jackson JSON and its working with it. With Moshi its throwing this error. I will rely with Jackson JSON library.